# Suggestion on DB Design to log user activity in a system

Tags: database, database-design, logging

I would like to ask a for an advice for a good database design to log user activity.

Currently I am implementing such approach for a simple website where user can post/edit/delete an article on the website.

**Table Logbook**

```
- log_id
- log_change[Enum: new/edit/remove]
- log_date
- member_id
- post_id
```

**Table Post**

```
- post_id
- post_title
- etc....
```

**Table Member**

```
- member_id
- member_username
- member_pwd
- etc..
```

Using this table, everytime user makes a new post (or edit/remove) of an article it will be logged on the Logbook (along with the time when it happens).

However, what if I am dealing with a larger system where not only user can post an article but do other things such as login/logout (from the system), make a purchase (transaction).

Should I go for different table for each module?. For example, if the system has modules like Posting article, E-commerce, etc.. hence I would have log tables for:

1. Article Log
2. E-Commerce Log

Where each table will log activity in each corresponding module.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an entity sub-typing design approach, where common log attributes, like *who* and *when* are tracked in a single table for all types of changes.  For changes that have additional attributes you can have additional tables, one for each type.

Each of the sub-type log tables reference the common table using a foreign key.  Typically the foreign key from the sub-type table to the common table is also the primary key of the sub-type table, i.e. the relationship is 1:1.

In such a design, the common table often includes a column (*partitioning attribute*) which indicates which sub-type is applicable to each record in the common table.

This approach reduces the amount of code you need to build and maintain your logging system while allowing you to keep your log tables normalized.

Comment: Thanks, this clarify things a bit.